# Detect verticality of iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, gyroscope, core-motion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get pitch, roll and yaw relative to geographic north on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313474/get-pitch-roll-and-yaw-relative-to-geographic-north-on-ios)

Is there a way to detect that iPhone is vertical?

Gyroscope gives us absolute angle relative to a position.

But how can I know if this relative position corresponds to a vertical position?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
    // device is currently in portrait (vertical) orientation
}
```

Comment: As I noted in my answer, be sure to read the class docs for info on ensuring you get a valid value back.

Comment: I wanna make AR app. 

Put some annotation to building :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking for precise angular information, just macro orientation, inspect `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`.

Be sure to read the class documentation for some important implementation details.

Comment: ^^ this solve my problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313474/get-pitch-roll-and-yaw-relative-to-geographic-north-on-ios