# Get vertical rotation iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, magnetometer

I'm developing an app in which I'm getting iPhone's movements.
The iPhone should be taken vertically while the app is running, then I've implemented the accelerometer which helps me to analyze inclination, but I can't study the rotation with it.
So I need to analyze magnetometer rotation, but I don't know if I can use it also if I have the iPhone vertically.

Has anybody already implemented some code for this use?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use CoreMotion. It has built in functions for accessing the six-axis motion.

Comment: So there are delegate method in coremotion which let me manage the magnetometer?

Comment: No, you don't manage any of them separately. Instead you look at the attitude of the device returned by core motion. The attitude of the device is calculated by core motion taking the accelerometers, gyroscopes and magnetometer in to consideration.

Comment: See here... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009943 and here... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMDeviceMotion

Comment: Perfect, I'll check! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
    // device is currently in portrait (vertical) orientation
}
```

Also, possible duplicate of this : [Detect verticality of iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594144/detect-verticality-of-iphone)

Comment: My question is: can I manage iPhone rotation, using magnetometer, even in portrait mode?

Comment: As far as i know, the accelerometer and the gyroscope work in every mode. I could be wrong though